# SDE into ODE problem

Tags: option-pricing

Let S be the solution of the SDE:
$dS_t = g(S_t)dt + \sqrt S_tdW_t, \; S_0 ∈ (1, 2)$, where $g(·)$ is a bounded function.
Let $τ$ be the exit time $τ = min(t ≥ 0 : S_t ≥ 2 \; or \; S_t ≤ 1)$.
Obtain ODE for the function $f(x), x ∈ (1, 2)$, such that $f(S_0) = P(S_τ = 2)$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

(My attempt is based on $f(S_t)$, $0\leq t \leq \tau$, being a local martingale.)

We first note that:
$$\tau = \min \{\tau_1, \tau_2  \} $$
where
$$\tau_1 = \inf \{t\geq 0 | S_t =1 \}, \; \; \tau_2 = \inf \{t\geq 0 | S_t =2 \}$$
and
$$ \{ S_\tau = 2\} = \{ \tau = \tau_2 \} = \{\tau_2 < \tau_1 \}.  $$
Aslo, we note that the standard Lipschitz conditions for a time-homogenous Markov diffusion are not met, but more refined ones (Yamada-Watanabe) hold. In particular, the diffusion coefficient is Holder continuous with exponent $1/2$ as $|\sqrt{x} -\sqrt{y}|\leq \sqrt{|x-y|}$ for all $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$. (Caveat: I'm not sure if the boundness of the drift coefficient function $g$ is sufficient; it might need to be assumed Lipschitz.)

From Revuz & Yor, Continous Martingales and Brownian Motion, Chapter VII, Propositions (3.2) and (3.5), we have:

1. There exists a continuous, strictly increasing function $\phi$, called scale function, such that, for the solution $(S^x_t)_{t\geq 0}$ for SDE started at time $0$ with $S_0=x\in (1,2)$,
   $$ f(x) := P(S^x_\tau=2)=P_x(\tau_2 < \tau_1) = \frac{\phi(x) - \phi(1)}{\phi(2) -\phi(1)} $$
2. The process $\phi(S_t)$, $0\leq t < \tau$, is a local martingale.

Applying Ito Lemma to $\phi(S_t)$ we get:
$$ d\phi(S_t) = \phi^{'}(S_t)dS_t + 0.5\phi^{''}(S_t)(dS_t)^2$$
$$ = \left( g(S_t)\phi^{'}(S_t) + 0.5S_t\phi^{''}(S_t) \right) dt + \sqrt{S_t}\phi^{'}(S_t)dW_t,$$
whose drift needs to be $0$, leading to the ODE:
$$ g(x)\phi^{'}(x) + 0.5x\phi^{''}(x) =0 $$
and
$$  g(x)f^{'}(x) + 0.5xf^{''}(x) =0, $$
$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^+} f(x) = 0, \; \; \lim_{x\rightarrow 2^-} f(x) = 1. $$